# Remove profiles completely on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-registry, user-profiles, network-profiles

I've set a Group Policy to remove user profiles not used for 30 days, they are training machines. This functions and removes them from the user profiles list (see borrowed image) but leaves the registry key and profile folder in C:\Users. A known 'feature' when using GP to remove profiles.

What's the easiest way to clean up these reg keys and old profile folders? Some old profile folders just contain an ntuser.dat file.

Preferred methods are Powershell, bat file or Autohotkey exe (that can be run remotely as Admin using PDQ) or other native Windows function.

PC OS is Win7 or Win10.
[image]

Comment: We're not a script writing service, however I have provided an answer that shows the 'usual' steps to completely delete a user profile. Ideally, however, it might be a good idea, if you are running a training environment, to use virtual machines and take snapshots of them once they are prepared, ready for training, and then restore the snapshots when training is complete/ready for the next session.

Comment: @kinnectus. I did not request any scripts be written only that that is the preferred method. 3rd party software is not to be used. Only Windows scripting or if an AHK file was already available; so the code could be scrutinised. I don't want to reinvent the 'wheel' if I overlooked the obvious, which it seems I haven't. More digging it is then.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to completely delete Windows profiles is:

1. Delete the user's profile folder from `C:\Users` (manually or scripted)
2. Using regedit (either manually or scripted) remove the user's registry key from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`. Note you will need to identify the user's SID to ensure the correct profile is removed from registry.

**Warning (from Microsoft):**

> Using Registry Editor incorrectly can cause serious, system-wide
>   problems that may require you to re-install Windows to correct them.
>   Microsoft cannot guarantee that any problems resulting from the use of
>   Registry Editor can be solved. Use this tool at your own risk.

Comment: That is what I am after automating. I have a 1000+ computers to manage so visiting each one is not practical.

Comment: @AndyAnderson Hi Andy. Please see the comment on your question explaining that we aren't a script writing service. However of you write your own script and get stuck in the process that's something this site can help with.